# Regex in Java matching specific special characters with number

Tags: java, regex

I would like to have a regex which accepts numeric along with specific special characters (`.-,`). I just learned about basics of regex and I don't know how come my pattern doesn't work, really need advice.

**My Pattern**

```
   ^(([0-9]*)+[.,\-]{0,1})$
```

(`.,-`) can only be repeated once, that's `{0,1}`. Also first should be numeric and last would also be numeric. I really need a little push.

**Expected output**

```
122-555-1521 //true

155--122 //false

155,- //false

.-12 //false

123.123. //false

.12 //false

1.2,1-3 //true
```

Comment: can you show us some expected outputs?

Comment: You can use: `^\d+(?:[.,-]\d+)*$`

Comment: (OT: `{0,1}` is shorter, and more commonly, written `?`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the simple pattern `^(?:\d+[.,-])*\d+$`

- several digits : `\d+`
- one char from `.,-` : `[.,-]`
- you can repeat the 2 previous elements : `(?:\d[.,-])*` ()`?:` non-capture for performance)
- digits at the end : `\d+`

```
String[] array = {"122-555-1521", "155--122", "155,-", ".-12", "123.123."};
String pattern = "^(?:\\d+[.,-])*\\d+$";
for(String str : array){
    System.out.println(str+" "+str.matches(pattern));
}

122-555-1521 true
155--122     false
155,-        false
.-12         false
123.123.     false
```

[***Working Demo***](https://ideone.com/mDt6v2) - [***Regex Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/bCOddd/1)

Comment: 'thanks for the answer with explanations of the patterns :) I;m very grateful thanks

Comment: Better to use: `^(?:\d+[.,-])*\d+$`

Comment: @anubhava better for ? If you don't care about capture or not-capture no need of `?:`

Comment: Better in terms of performance because `^(\d+[\.,-]?)*\d+$` backtracks and takes many times more steps to complete due to `?` quantifier. [Check this demo and see # of steps taken](https://regex101.com/r/GsTn9D/1) Using non-capture group and not escaping dot inside character class are just minor improvements.

Comment: can i ask what is the use of that ?: and capture and not-capture? is there a difference

Comment: Using non-capture group is better as it saves memory while processing a large text. Read this tutorial on groups: https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: @kenjirojaucian capture is when you need a precise part of the string, like https://regex101.com/r/MdLo8C/1

Comment: im confused,, ? stands for optional right,, then where exactly there is the symbol for capturing and non capture,,and for precise string i thought use of [ ] for precise strings,,hope you guys bear with me,im noob at this

Comment: @kenjirojaucian () captures, (?:) non capture

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to match groups of digits, separated by single non-digit characters from the set of [.,-]?

[0-9]+([.,\-][0-9]+)*

Comment: sorry i can't use this cause it also accepts spaces

Comment: You're right, I left out the ^ and $. 

However, azro's answer is more detailed and uses the more compact \d, so better than mine anyway.